# Herencia en Java

Tags: java

Quería implementar una clase la cual va a servir para representar puntos en el espacio. Para ello hace uso de tres atributos (coordenadas x, y, z) de los cuales, dos de esas coordenadas existen en otra clase y de una serie de métodos que existen en una clase que representa puntos en el plano. Dicha clase tiene una serie de métodos

Método `coordinates()`: Devuelve un array con las coordenadas de los puntos

Método `equals()`: Evalúa si las coordenadas son iguales o no

Método `toString()`: Representa las coordenadas

**Problemas que tengo en la segunda clase:** Al heredar el método `.toString()` y agregarle `+` la coordenada `z`no se representa de la forma `(x, y, z)` sino como `(x, y)z`

Por último, al heredar el método `coordinates()` solo se representa de la forma `[x, y]`no me deja agregar la coordenada `z`

**Clase puntos en el plano**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Point2D {

    protected double x, y;

    public Point2D(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double[] coordinates() {
        double[] result = {this.x, this.y};
        return result;
    }

    @Override   
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Point2D iterable = (Point2D)other; 
        if (other instanceof Point2D) {
            return Arrays.equals(this.coordinates(), iterable.coordinates());
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override   
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.stream(this.coordinates()).mapToObj(Double::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "(", ")"));
    }
```

**Clase puntos en el espacio heredada de la clase puntos en el plano**

```
public class Point3D extends Point2D {

    protected double z; 

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;     
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Point3D cast = (Point3D) other;
        if (other instanceof Point3D) {
            return this.coordinates() == cast.coordinates();
        } else {
            return false;
          }
    }

    @Override 
    public double[] coordinates() {
        return super.coordinates();         // Problema: Expected output = [x, y, z] 
    }                                       //           Output recibido: [x, y]

    @Override   
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + this.z;   // Problema: Expected output = (x, y, z)
    }                                       //           Output recibido = (x, y)z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu clase Point3D debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
public class Point3D extends Point2D {

    protected double z; 

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;     
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        Point3D cast = (Point3D) other;
        if (other instanceof Point3D) {
            return this.coordinates() == cast.coordinates();
        } else {
            return false;
          }
    }

    @Override 
    public double[] coordinates() {
        return new double[]{this.x, this.y, this.z};
    }

    @Override   
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", "+ this.z + ")";
    }                                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El método toString al recibir la herencia debes reescribirlo completo para que te funcione como tu deseas y también el resto de métodos que no te funcionan como tu quieres. Para el método toString te quedaría algo así:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
     return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", "+ this.z + ")";
}
```